# CUDA surface memory unbind

Tags: cuda, textures, cuda-arrays

When using texture memory in CUDA, we call `cudaBindTextureToArray(texRef, cuArray, channelDesc)`, use the texture, and then unbind it:

```
cudaUnbindTexture(texRef);
```

With surface memory, there is an analogous `cudaBindSurfaceToArray(surfRef, cuArray);`

but in the [Documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#surface-memory) I have not found any mention of unbinding the surface, and my guess `cudaUnbindSurface(surfRef);` throws an error. Is surface reference unbinding not necessary/impossible and why is this different from texture reference?